# Extending MVC3 HTML Helpers to include custom HTML5 Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I know I can add custom attributes to any given helper using an anonymous type with the attribute and value specified for it to be rendered as a HTML5 attribute however im looking to achieve the same across all HTML Helpers in a given view triggered by an externally specified helper.  Similar to the same functionality you receive from the un-obtrusive JavaScript helper where it renders validation rules in the context of a form field's attributes.

Does anyone know if there is a "simple" way to inject these customisations into the helpers, or will I need to extend each of the helpers independently?

Cheers

Comment: can you give a concrete example of what you want? You may be able to use Templated Razor Delegates (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx).

Comment: We're looking to do some work on the client side depending on a form's field being changed.  Our desired approach was to add a custom attribute with the original field's value then onChange do a compare on the new value and the old..  meaning someone can return a field to its original state and it not be considered changed.  So the idea was, each helper (textbox, select input etc) would render the attributes automatically.

Comment: instead of using a custom attribute, it would be easier to use jQuery to go through each field and store the original values when the document is ready.  You then can check the field's original value when a field is changed, and take your actions accordingly.

Comment: @councellorben, that was my original solution which was declined by my boss was was looking for a plan b.

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend all methods from one centralized point (write code that will extend all your html helper methods by adding overload with additional 'htmlAttributes' parameter - may be it is possible by using IL methods generation, but it is hard way).

Each extension should be overload of your html helper method, and you can implement like in example:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string MyPager(this HtmlHelper html, string parameter1, int parameter2)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("div");
        GenerateMyPagerBody(builder , parameter1, parameter2); // insert body into tag
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    }

    public static string MyPager(this HtmlHelper html, string parameter1, int parameter2, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("div");
        GenerateMyPagerBody(builder , parameter1, parameter2);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    }
}
```