# Can create dynamic razor code in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic-programming

I would create a dynamic razor code in the MVC view

for example:

string RazorTag = "Label"

@Html."RazorTag"(model => model.someAttribute)

Comment: exist a method for do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension methods with custom functionality, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262473/extending-mvc3-html-helpers-to-include-custom-html5-attribute/6262766#6262766)

Or even create your own helpers, like [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148662/creating-custom-helper-available-in-views)

But in both cases you must create additional classes.

Comment: please ,Can you do a simple example ?